# Difference between GCC and CLANG about using-directive scope in C++ modules

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++20

When I put an unexported "using namespace" directive in a C++20 module interface file, it also applies to the separate module implementation file under CLANG, but not under GCC. So, which one is right according to the current standards ?

Note : My version of CLANG is 16.0.6, whereas my version of GCC is 13.2.1.

I know there are many topics dealing with "using" and "modules" available here, however it may be hard to find the details allowing to answer my specific case with precision. This is like if the standard changed since 2020, this would explain a possible difference between the compilers and the difficulty to retrieve convincing information.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce the behaviour : There are three source files, "library.h", "interface.ixx", and "implementation.cxx".

**library.h** :

```
#ifndef RAG_DOLL_h
#define RAG_DOLL_h

namespace rag {

    class Doll {};

};

#endif
```

**interface.ixx** :

```
export module xd;

import <library.h>;

using namespace rag;
```

**implementation.cxx** :

```
module xd;

import <library.h>;

Doll kore;
```

This last line "`Doll kore;`" is the one GCC dislikes, it triggers the following error :

```
implementation.cxx:5:1: error: 'Doll' does not name a type
    5 | Doll kore;
      | ^~~~
```

Of course, replacing it by "`rag::Doll kore;`" fixes the error. CLANG is fine without this fix, so what is going on ? What about the standard ?

Since finding the proper arguments to compile modules may be a little hard, I'm also giving the content of two additional files, one executable script per compiler : "gcc.sh" and "clang.sh".

**gcc.sh** :

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=C
prg="`realpath "$0"`" && cd "`dirname "$prg"`" || exit $?
ln -sf interface.ixx interface.cxx \
&& g++ -c -fmodules-ts -I. -fmodule-header library.h \
&& g++ -c -fmodules-ts -I. interface.cxx -o interface.o \
&& g++ -c -fmodules-ts -I. implementation.cxx -o implementation.o
rm -rf gcm.cache interface.cxx
```

**clang.sh** :

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=C
prg="`realpath "$0"`" && cd "`dirname "$prg"`" || exit $?
ln -sf interface.ixx interface.cxxm \
&& clang++ -std=c++20 -I. -fmodule-header library.h -o library.pcm \
&& clang++ -std=c++20 -I. --precompile interface.cxxm -fmodule-file=library.pcm -o interface.pcm \
&& clang++ -std=c++20 -I. -c implementation.cxx -fmodule-file=library.pcm -fmodule-file=xd=interface.pcm -o implementation.o
rm -f library.pcm interface.cxxm
```

They require a Unix shell to run, and must be put in the same directory that the one containing the source files.

Thank you for reading, and I hope this is not an implementation-defined feature...

Comment: Looks like GCC's **modules** support isn't entirely finished yet.  https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#:~:text=Modules

Comment: Indeed, although it would be interesting to check if this is the effective cause of the difference, I would like to reach a kind of certainty because knowing the intended scope of "using namespace" in module interfaces may have consequences on the choice to forbid its use in some project custom programming rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang is correct here: **all** declarations in one module unit are available in another unit of the same module that imports it.  (Non-partition implementation units implicitly import the module’s interface units.)  The *using-directive* being available implies that it affects the importer.  (You can export it to affect **external** importers, although maybe you shouldn’t.)

GCC’s omission may derive from the fact that C++20 as published didn’t really address this question since it phrased the declaration availability in terms of **scopes** that might or might not extend across translation units.

Comment: So if I understand well, the scope "might or might not extend across translation units" in general, but the "might not" part doesn't apply to different units of a same module because "all declarations in one module unit are available [...]", and GCC is actually wrong about this. Thank you for your short and precise answer, this transmission of the using-declaration is sad for modules that extend a single library with plenty of inline methods in their interface while they call many other third-party functions in their implementation, but for sure this is the most consistent design.

Comment: @Morgana: By "might or might not" I just meant the standard as published was unclear; the current wording is very explicit about using "precedes" to indicate when an import might make a declaration have an effect on the importer.  To be clear, the "transmission" of the *using-directive* is only within the module that declares it (unless it's exported), so the module's author can address any name collisions locally.

Comment: Ah ! Ok, thanks for this extra precision.
Just to add useless statements : Yes I had already understood that unexported using-directives remained only in the module, and I totally agree with the implied assertion that exporting them further is evil. (And let me guess... This is the first time you have to clarify the expression "might or might not" since you were born, isn't it ?)